# Deriving Poisson Summation Formula

Tags: number-theory

Note: I know that Poisson Summation has been discussed here before, but I have not seen this version. This is from Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory, page 14.

First we have a real, continuous and 'monotonic in streches' function $f(x)$. (I am not sure what 'monotonic in stretches' means). Then take $f_1(x)$ coincide with $f(x)$ for $0 \leq x < 1$ and be defined elsewhere by periodicity. Then the Fourier series of $f_1(x)$ is

$\frac{1}{2} a_0 + \sum_{v=1}^{\infty}(a_v \cos 2\pi v x + b_v \sin 2 \pi v x)$ where $\frac{1}{2} a_v = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \cos 2 \pi v x dx$, $\frac{1}{2} b_v = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin 2 \pi v x dx$.

The above series converges for all x, its sum is $f_1(x)$ at a point of continuity of $f_1(x)$, and is the mean of left and right values of $f_1(x)$ at a point of ordinary discontinuity. I guess everything is about the theory of Fourier series expansion up to here, (I also appreciate suggestions for studying it, I just randomly read some stuff), so I will accept them for now.

Then, take x=0 and get

$\frac{1}{2} [f(0) + f(1)] = \frac{1}{2} a_0 + \sum_{v=1}^{\infty} a_v = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \cos 2 \pi v x dx$.

As far as I understood, the first term should be about "The above series is the mean of left and right values of $f_1(x)$ at a point of ordinary discontinuity" since the point $0$ really is the point of discontinuity of $f_1(x)$ by its definition. The second is when we plug in $x=0$ to the above summation, but I do not understand the equalities. I appreciate any help!

Note: Then the Poisson summation formula follows by generalizing this case, (which is $A=0, B=1$) and the formula is:

$\sum_{n=A}^{n=B} f(n) = \sum_{v= -\infty}^{\infty} \int_{A}^{B} f(x) e^{2 \pi i vx} dx  $
where it is necessary to replace the end points A and B by $\frac{f(A)}{2}$ and $\frac{f(B)}{2}$.

I am not sure if I understood how to generalize but I feel like I need to first understand the above equalities that I ask, and it is too much to ask at once, so I need to go step by step.

Comment: :)) i will edit that but i laughed a lot, thank you!

Comment: Usually the Poisson formula is written $\sum_n f(n) = A \sum_k \hat{f}(v)$ where $\hat{f}$ is the *Fourier Transform* in order to underline its symmetry.